# Canonicalization of semi-duplicates and different notations

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, usage

Ich habe mit Listen der Ausdrücke zu tun, die dauernd verschiedene Schreibweisen enthalten.

Beispiele:

| Bezeichnungsvariante | id |
| --- | --- |
| verkehrsrechtsschutz rückwirkend | 50 |
| verkehrs-rechtsschutz rückwirkend | 50 |
| familien rechtsschutzversicherung | 100 |
| familienrechtsschutzversicherung | 100 |
| privat rechtsschutz ohne wartezeit | 20 |
| privater rechtsschutz ohne wartezeit | 20 |
| rechtsschutzversicherung strafrecht | 80 |
| strafrechtsschutz | 80 |
| rechtsschutzversicherung gewerbe | 200 |
| rechtsschutzversicherung gewerblich | 200 |
| fahrer rechtsschutz | 160 |
| fahrerrechtsschutz | 160 |
| fahrer-rechtsschutz | 160 |

Ich möchte diese Listen so verarbeiten, dass sie nur *kanonische* Schreibweisen enthalten, also Singular und *eine* korrekte Schreibweise. Wenn die Liste mehrere korrekte Schreibweisen eines Ausdrucks hat, sollen alle beibehalten werden.

Wie nennt sich diese Deduplizierung korrekt? Ich suche ein Terminus technicus für diese Prozedur.

Comment: Nur ein kleiner HInweis: In der Beispielliste ist nicht eine Schreibweise korrekt, da dort alle Substantive mit einem Kleinbuchstaben beginnen. Zur Frage selbst: vielleicht so etwas wie „*Reduktion* bis auf korrekte Schreibweisen“?

Comment: Auch, wenn ich bereits mit einem generischen Begriff für den Vorgang geantwortet habe, bitte ich um eine Klarstellung oder möchte zumindest darauf hinweisen, dass der beschriebene Vorgang noch leicht unterspezifiziert ist: Mehrere "korrekte" Schreibweisen sollen also beibehalten werden, "inkorrekte" Schreibweisen sollen dann, soweit ich verstanden habe, in "die korrekte" überführt werden. Aber wenn es mehrere korrekte Schreibweisen für manche Ausdrücke gibt, kann dann sinnvoll entschieden werden, in welche davon ein inkorrekter Eintrag überführt werden muss?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper die Frage habe ich mir auch gestellt. Mir fiel folgende Vorgehensweise ein: bei mehr als nur einer "richtigen" Schreibweise würde ich die Zahlen aus der zweiten Kolumne bewerten. Sind die Zahlen gleich - bleiben alle "korrekten" Schreibweisen in der Liste, ansonsten werden die Schreibweisen mit der kleineren Zahl entfernt.

Comment: @Evgeniy: Je nachdem, wie stabil/nachvollziehbar die Zahlen zustande kommen, mag das funktionieren oder mehr oder weniger zufällige Ergebnisse erzeugen. Eine alternative Möglichkeit wäre vermutlich, verschiedene "korrekte" Schreibweisen in *jedem* Fall zu einem Eintrag zusammenzufassen (der das beschriebene "Konzept" repräsentiert); dieser Eintrag kann aber beliebig viele "korrekte" alternative Namen haben. (Aber jetzt wird es off-topic für hier und passender für SO ;) )

Comment: Die gegebenen Begriffe sind noch nicht elementar: *privat* oder *gewerblich* ist ein Aussage über den Adressatenkreis, *rückwirkend* oder *ohne Wartezeit* eine Aussage über das Inkrafttreten.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bei der beschriebenen Operation handelt es sich um den Vorgang, Daten, die in zahlreichen Formen vorliegen können, in eine einheitliche Form zu bringen. Ein solcher Prozess wird im Allgemeinen **Normalisierung** genannt.

Das drückt freilich nicht aus, was nun konkret in deinem Fall geschieht, sondern eher die Intention, die Textbestandteile in eine einheitliche, wie du sagst "kanonische" Form zu überführen. Welche Normalisierung nun konkret durchgeführt wird, könnte eventuell durch zusätzliche Einschränkungen beschrieben werden - so ist es auch bei weit verbreiteten Beispielen üblich, beispielsweise bei der "Unicode-Normalisierung", welche Sonderzeichen in Texten, die auf verschiedene Weise codiert werden können, in ein festes Schema überführt.

Das Ergebnis/Ziel einer Normalisierung ist eine **Normalform**, wobei auch die Verwandtschaft der beiden Wörter erkennbar wird.

Comment: Das war auch der erste Begriff, der mir einfiel. Allerdings gehen bei der Normalisierung keine Informationen verloren, worüber man hier diskutieren kann, ob dem hier so ist. Aber guter Kandidat.

Comment: @mtwde: Also, zumindest [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalisierung_(Text)) meint bezüglich "Normalisierung (Text)", dass "nur die für den gewünschten Kontext relevanten Informationen beibehalten werden". Ich stimme dieser Definition nicht unbedingt zu (weil ich den Wegfall von Informationen eher für einen möglichen und akzeptablen Seiteneffekt als die definierende Eigenschaft (oder gar das Ziel) einer Normalisierung sehe/kenne), aber sie drückt immerhin eindeutig aus, dass zumindest nach Kenntnisstand der Autoren bei der Normalisierung Informationen wegfallen können.

Comment: @mtwde: Nachtrag: Wenn man so darüber nachdenkt, geht vermutlich bei *fast* jeder Normalisierung eine Information verloren, und zwar die ursprüngliche Darstellungsform der Daten vor der Normalisierung. Einzige Ausnahme stellen hier Normalisierungen dar, deren Ziel-Normalform explizit die ursprüngliche Darstellung enthält.

Answer (score 3):

Deduplizierung ist schon nicht schlecht. Alternativ: **Standardisierung**.

Answer (score 2):

Da du den Begriff in deiner Frage schon selbst benutzt hast, um das Problem zu beschreiben, kann man das Ganze doch gleich

> Kanonisierung

nennen.

> Der Begriff der Kanonisierung (von hebr. qana »Stab, Meßrohr«, als Fremdwort ins Griechische übernommen) beschreibt den Prozeß, in dem ein Bestand von Symbolen, Texten, Handlungen oder Artefakten als maßgeblich und normativ festgeschrieben wird.

<sup>[[Quelle]](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-476-03703-9_55)</sup>

Comment: Das Problem mit der Kanonisierung, das ich habe: ich finde zu diesem Begriff keine Python oder R-Bibliothek, die im NLP-Bereich agieren würde. Normalization ist da.mehr passend. Aber ja, der Begriff an sich passt durchaus: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonicalization

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/kanonisieren) nennt unter Bedeutung 2 von kanonisieren noch als Synonyme: angleichen, anpassen, eichen, harmonisieren, normieren, standardisieren, unifizieren und (meiner Meinung nach am besten:) **vereinheitlichen**.